# Vector tile selection layer (canvas) drawn outside the map div. Bug?

Tags: select, vector-layer, openlayers

I loaded a PBF vector tile layers into my map, and when I select a feature, OpenLayers 6.3.1 creates the selected layer canvas outside the map.
Is it a general problem, or just mine?

I don't attach any personal code, because I encounter the same error on the official site:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html

[image: ol6 vector selection bug]

Comment: Coding questions on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise question is most likely to get closed.

Comment: Maybe my text was not obvious. i modified it. Thx

Comment: Yes, it was a bug and it has been fixed in the development version https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-tile-selection.html

Comment: Thank you! I will check this page also in the future.